# Creating a VPN between Fedora 22 and Windows 10

Tags: nginx, vpn, windows-10, fedora-22

This is my first post I have made here so please, be gentle.

I am fairly new to the server game but I want to setup a development environment for myself and a few others to help us build an app for both android and IOS. So far we have set up an nginx server with php-fpm and php5 using Fedora 22 and have plans to use git for version control and Ionic to port our code to both android and IOS. What I can't seem to figure out is how to set up a VPN between my remote windows machine and the Linux server we have set up. Ideally I want to be able to map our git directory to my windows file explorer and then access files served from our server via the browser. All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Don't do that. Git has plenty of mechanisms to let you interact with remote repositories. You already have SSH access to the server (presumably), and git is very happy to push/pull over SSH. You may need a VPN to your server for other reasons, but git should not be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

*You should not work with git over vpn because ssh connections with push/pull are the idea behind the git system.*

But if you need a vpn service between Windows and Unix for other reasons, you should start with **OPENVPN**.

https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html